# C# Socket message are mixed

Tags: c#, sockets

When i send many messages from the client to the server, i receive half of the second packet in the first packet.

For example, i send

JOHN 1000

MARK 2000

I receive JOHN 1000 MARK

2000

This is my reader:

```
private void ReceiveData()
{
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    while (isConnected && _stream.CanRead)
    {
        try
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = _stream.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
            receiveMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            _stream.Flush();

            if(receiveMsg == "")
                return ;

            Debug.Log("[Recv] " + receiveMsg);
            receiveMsg = "";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is your _buffer?

Comment: private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];

Answer (score 0):

A TCP connection is a *stream of bytes*. When you write one message (as a byte array) to the stream, and then another, there is no way for the receiver to know where one message ends and the next message begins.

You need to add some way for your client to know when it has received a complete message - one common approach is to pick one byte, and use that to represent the end of the message (a delimiter). C# has `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, which could be used for this purpose. Call `ReadLine()` or `WriteLine()`, and the end of your messages will be marked with a newline character.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to avoid misreading from a specific socket?

Comment: I'm going to analyze with a case switch every single packet, and i'm going to give some parameters for each packet, for example:

MOVE#X#Y\r\n

Comment: Hi Alessandro, can you be a bit more specific about misreading from a specific socket? What do you mean by that? Also, in regards to the case switch, that approach will work, but over time as you add more and more types of packets, it gets much harder to maintain. I'd recommend having a look at the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) as an alternative. The wikipedia article is rather intense, but 'Gang of Four' explain it nicely: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/command.aspx